# Build error with nextjs: found page without a React Component as default export

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, netlify

I have nextjs project in which I want to prerender pages that contain terms of service.
There are saved as markdown file in
`public/tos/tos-en.md`
`public/tos/tos-pl.md`.

Inside `pages/tos/[locale]/index.jsx` I created following react component:

```
// import { unified } from 'unified'
// import remarkParse from 'remark-parse'
// import remarkHtml from 'remark-html'
// import fs from 'fs'

import matter from 'gray-matter'
import ReactMarkdown from 'react-markdown'

export default function Index({ content, data: frontMatter }) {
  console.log(content)
  console.log(frontMatter)
  return (
    <div className="p-8">
      Title: {frontMatter.title}
      <ReactMarkdown className="prose lg:prose-xl mx-auto">
        {content}
      </ReactMarkdown>
      {/* <div
          className="prose lg:prose-xl mx-auto"
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: content }}>
        </div> */}
    </div>
  )
}

// export function getStaticPaths = async () => {
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  return {
    paths: [{ params: { locale: 'en' } }, { params: { locale: 'pl' } }],
    fallback: false,
  }
}

// export function getInitialProps = async ({params}) => {
export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  console.log('Current locale: ', params.locale)
  // const fileData = fs.readFileSync(`public/tos/tos-${params.locale}.md`, 'utf8')

  // Import our .md file using the `slug` from the URL
  const markdownFile = await import(
    `../../../public/tos/tos-${params.locale}.md`
  )

  // Parse .md data through `matter`
  let parsedFile = matter(markdownFile.default)

  parsedFile.content = String(parsedFile.content)

  delete parsedFile.orig

  console.log(parsedFile)
  // let content = ''
  // await unified()
  //   .use(remarkParse)
  //   .use(remarkHtml)
  //   .process(fileData)
  //   .then((file) => {
  //   //   console.log(String(file))
  //     content = String(file)
  //   })

  return {
    props: parsedFile,
    // props: { data: {title: 'asda'} },
  }
}
```

I works when I run `npm run dev` (`next dev`), but when I try to deploy by creating production build `npm run build` (`next build`) I received following error:

```
> Build error occurred
Error: Build optimization failed: found page without a React Component as default export in 
pages/tos/[locale]

See https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/page-without-valid-component for more info.
```

Which is strange because component is exported. I tried to use separate export but the result is the same. I tried to move the file from `pages/tos/[locale]/index.jsx` to `pages/tos/[index].jsx` but that didn't seem to work as well.

Content of `public/tos/tos-en.md`:

```
---
title: "test"
date: "2020-10-01"
---

# TERMS OF SERVICE

### OVERVIEW

This website is...
```

Content of `public/tos/tos-pl.md`:

```
---
title: "test"
date: "2020-10-01"
---
# WARUNKI KORZYSTANIA Z USŁUGI


###
```

Content of package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@headlessui/react": "^1.4.0",
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^2.7.1",
    "@popperjs/core": "2.9.1",
    "@reach/portal": "^0.16.0",
    "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.4.1",
    "aws4": "^1.11.0",
    "clsx": "^1.1.1",
    "dayjs": "^1.10.7",
    "gray-matter": "^4.0.3",
    "imagemin-optipng": "^8.0.0",
    "joi": "^17.4.2",
    "mongoose": "^5.13.8",
    "nanoid": "^3.1.25",
    "next": "^11.0.1",
    "next-i18next": "^8.6.0",
    "next-optimized-images": "^2.6.2",
    "raw-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.12.2",
    "react-icons": "^4.2.0",
    "react-markdown": "^7.0.1",
    "react-modal": "^3.14.3",
    "realm-web": "^1.3.0",
    "remark-html": "^15.0.0",
    "remark-parse": "^10.0.0",
    "sharp": "^0.29.1",
    "styled-jsx": "^4.0.1",
    "swiper": "^6.8.3",
    "swr": "^0.5.6",
    "unified": "^10.1.0",
    "yup": "^0.32.9"
  },
```

edit: added package.json

Comment: Have you tried deleting the `.next` folder and building the app again?

Comment: hi @juliomalves ! Yea, I did that with no result.

Comment: I've found that commenting out the getStaticPaths and getStaticProps makes the error go away but that is not a real solution.

Comment: Looking at next.js source the error is thrown in file: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/73928c01f13f46a5d2ff0a2105e0877e7b1e2ef2/packages/next/build/index.ts

Around line: 1326

Comment: INVALID_DEFAULT_EXPORT error is thrown from: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/3667eba38559e5ccb810bade4779cda3649f1413/packages/next/build/utils.ts:879

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the next code.

The is error function requires the err object to include name and message attributes
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/packages/next/lib/is-error.ts

In my case I'm getting an error object without those and instead has an array of errors. This means the page is added to the invalidPages list which is fine but the reason given by next can be incorrect and not related to not exporting a valid component as the default export.